# JAXB cannot locate a file from a relative path

Tags: java, file-io, jaxb

I'm trying to use Jaxb in order to unamrshal an xml file. for some reason that I don't understand, I cannot refer to any other location then a full path on my specific computer. In the code below, the commented line doesn't work, but only the one above it. the file does exist (in two locations) and the commented line does work on a diffrent class.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Monopoly.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
//unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File("resources/monopoly_config.xml" ));
unmarshaller.unmarshal(new File( "C:\\Users\\Lior\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Monopoly curr\\MonopolyServer\\src\\BoardInfoResources\\monopoly_config.xml"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**

Since you are deploying to a server (from your comments), why not load your XML using a ClassLoader?  In a server environment you wouldn't be able to count on the File object in the way that you want to (as you have already discovered):

```
ClassLoader cl = Monopoly.class.getClassLoader();
InputStream xml =
 cl.getResourceAsStream("resources/monopoly_config.xml");
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Monopoly.class);
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
Monopoly monopoly = (Monopoly) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
```

---

JAXB will allow you to unmarshal any valid file object.  And it will definitely unmarshal files created with relative paths (see answer below for an example):

- [How to unmarshal xml message with bad parent/child model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062882/how-to-unmarshal-xml-message-with-bad-parent-child-model/6062959#6062959)

In your example you will need to make sure that your working directory is set correctly.  Based that your full path is:

```
"C:\\Users\\Lior\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Monopoly curr\\MonopolyServer\\src\\BoardInfoResources\\monopoly_config.xml"
```

Assuming your working directory is:

```
"C:\\Users\\Lior\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Monopoly curr\\MonopolyServer\\src\\"
```

Your relative path appears to be wrong (since there is no resources directory):

```
"resources/monopoly_config.xml"
```

You may have meant it to be:

```
"BoardInfoResources/monopoly_config.xml"
```

Comment: This is the answer. Just to add to it, though, is you can check your current working directory by doing: System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));

Comment: Thank you for that. unfortunately, this doesn't solve it. Sorry if I wasn't clear earlier - both resources and BoardInfoResources exist and contain the xml, however, it will simply not work unless it's a full path.

Comment: @Lior - Did you check your working directory as suggested by Alvin?

Comment: yap, it is C:\Users\Lior\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Monopoly curr\MonopolyServer. I was able to make it run "on it's own", but when I try to deploy it to my server I get "java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\apache-tomcat-6.0.32\bin\src\BoardInfoResources\monopoly_config.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)]"

Comment: @Lior why don't you load it from the ClassLoader instead?  See my updated answer for details.

Comment: Any tips on how to avoid the need to restart netbeans, re install axis and rebooting so often? I keep getting to a point that I have to take these actions because deploy doesn't seem to effect..

Comment: @Lior - You may want to start a new question about this last issue, that may bring in the NetBeans and Axis people.