# JAXB endless data structure, recursive binding?

Tags: java, xml, data-binding, recursion, jaxb

sBefore starting a project I wanted to get a short heads up here.

If I have a structure like this:

```
<root>
<a>
    <a>
        <a>
            <a>
                <a/>
            </a>
        </a>
    </a>
    <a>
    </a>
</a>
```

The `a` element can hold `a` elements and this endlessly deep.

Do I just write a class A and then give it a List as a member? JAXB does the magic automatically then? Or is this structure not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can have the following:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class A {

    private List<A> a;

}
```

And your [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation will marshal it correctly.

**Related Example**

- [How to unmarshal xml message with bad parent/child model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6062882/how-to-unmarshal-xml-message-with-bad-parent-child-model/6062959#6062959)