# How to parse XML where I have tags with equal names but on differrent levels?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I implement some backend and I am trying to integrate with rest server which use XML as a transport. There is Spring which automatically handle XML parsing using JAXB. But some requests and responses which come from this server have tags with equal names. For example:

```
<transaction type="reserve">
  <date>2014-12-11</date>
  <station-from>London</station-from>
  <station-to>Paris</station-to>
  <place>1</place>
  <detail>
    <transaction id-seller="123">
      <some-tag>bla-bla</some-tag>
    </transaction>
  </detail>
</transaction>
```

Java code:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "transaction")
public class Transaction {

    private String date;
    private String stationFrom;
    private String stationTo;
    private int place;
    private Detail detail;

    public Transaction() {}

    @XmlElement(name = "date")
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "station-from")
    public String getStationFrom() {
        return stationFrom;
    }

    public void setStationFrom(String stationFrom) {
        this.stationFrom = stationFrom;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "station-to")
    public String getStationTo() {
        return stationTo;
    }

    public void setStationTo(String stationTo) {
        this.stationTo = stationTo;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "place")
    public int getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(int place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    @XmlRootElement(name = "detail")
    public static class Detail {

        private Transaction transaction;

        public Detail() {}

        @XmlElement(name = "transaction")
        public Transaction getTransaction() {
            return transaction;
        }

        public void setTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
            this.transaction = transaction;
        }

        @XmlRootElement(name = "transaction")
        public static class DetailTransaction {

            private String idSeller;
            private String someTag;

            public DetailTransaction() {}

            @XmlAttribute(name = "id-seller")
            public String getIdSeller() {
                return idSeller;
            }

            public void setIdSeller(String idSeller) {
                this.idSeller = idSeller;
            }

            @XmlAttribute(name = "some-tag")
            public String getSomeTag() {
                return someTag;
            }

            public void setSomeTag(String someTag) {
                this.someTag = someTag;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There are two tags which have equal name - transaction. How can I handle it by JAXB? I don't have XSD schema by the way, this service doesn't provide it. In tomcat I got this exception:

```
Two classes have the same XML type name "transaction". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
```

Actually this example has nothing to do with that complex responses which I got from this REST server, but the idea is there are many places where they use tags with equal names but in different places and on different levels.

Comment: have a look at this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17115355/parsing-nested-same-name-elements-using-jaxb)

Comment: Well of course it is possible. The Tomcat complains about equal type names, this is different from *element* names. Show us some code.

Comment: @stringy05 I don't think the OP is asking about recursion, I think it is a simple naming collission on types.

Comment: Yeah I was assuming the atts were both optional on the same type. In that case the namespaces need to be different (and thus the underlying jaxb types, which is exactly what tomcat is suggesting there).

Comment: I added code which I use for mapping. Please take a look at it, really don't know what to do :)

Comment: @stringy05 No, namespaces of elements don't have to be different! These must just be different types.

Answer (score 0):

I see the following problems:

- You have `@XmlRootElement`s everywhere.
- `Detail` uses `Transaction`, not `DetailTransaction`.
- Your `Transaction` misses getter/setter for `transaction`.

Try the following:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "transaction")
public class Transaction {

    private String date;
    private String stationFrom;
    private String stationTo;
    private int place;
    private Detail detail;

    public Transaction() {}

    @XmlElement(name = "date")
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "station-from")
    public String getStationFrom() {
        return stationFrom;
    }

    public void setStationFrom(String stationFrom) {
        this.stationFrom = stationFrom;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "station-to")
    public String getStationTo() {
        return stationTo;
    }

    public void setStationTo(String stationTo) {
        this.stationTo = stationTo;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "place")
    public int getPlace() {
        return place;
    }

    public void setPlace(int place) {
        this.place = place;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "detail")
    public Detail getDetail() {
        return detail;
    }

    public void setDetail(Detail detail) {
        this.detail = detail;
    }

    public static class Detail {

        private DetailTransaction transaction;

        public Detail() {}

        @XmlElement(name = "transaction")
        public DetailTransaction getTransaction() {
            return transaction;
        }

        public void setTransaction(DetailTransaction transaction) {
            this.transaction = transaction;
        }

        public static class DetailTransaction {

            private String idSeller;
            private String someTag;

            public DetailTransaction() {}

            @XmlAttribute(name = "id-seller")
            public String getIdSeller() {
                return idSeller;
            }

            public void setIdSeller(String idSeller) {
                this.idSeller = idSeller;
            }

            @XmlAttribute(name = "some-tag")
            public String getSomeTag() {
                return someTag;
            }

            public void setSomeTag(String someTag) {
                this.someTag = someTag;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Untested, just hacked your code a bit. And make a unit test (instantiate the context, unmarshal sample XML, marshal sample object) before testing with a real service.

Comment: It seems like without annotation @XmlRootElement for inner classes Detail and DetailTransaction it even doesn't work for Marshalling. Resulting xml file after marshalling is missing Detail tag.

Comment: @IgorBortnyk No, `@XmlRootElement`s are (generally) not required for inner elements, there must be some other problem. Please post you (ideally single-file) test case which reproduces the problem. You noticed that *your* code is missing the `detail` getter and setter, right?

Comment: I did all changes, but I still get error. My code is a little diferrent, I just created this example in SOF